# what different between import * as module and import module in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

When I write typescript:

I have this code:

```
import * as express from 'express'
```

and the system gives me an error:

```
Type originates at this import. A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime. Consider using a default import or import require here instead.
```

So, I change to:

```
import express from 'express'
```

what is the difference between them, why the first way can not called or constructed?

Comment: `as` is used when you want to give `alias name`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what is the difference between them

- `* as express` will import the *entire* contents of a module
- `express` is will import the default export only

> why the first way can not called or constructed?

A module itself is not callable as per the ES spec. So you wouldn't be able to do `express()` i.e. a function invocation. Therefore it must mapped to a *member* of the module, in this case the `default` export member